# Unicode font support in Blender

Tags: text-object

I have checked if there is an article on this subject and i found none, Unicode fonts support languages that have letter joint connections, like Arabic for example. While blender can support Unicode fonts only that it doesn't create the text shape 100% connected, it overlaps the letters to mimic joint letters just like illustrator or any vector based software, but in the end result you end up with overlapped vector creases and unwanted results. When rendering you get flickering shaders that gives you bad rap on your project especially when you deal with typography animations that has loads of text in it.

**here is a representation of a Unicode in blender and its results.**
[image]
[image]
**this is the result after rendering text using Unicode font.**
[image]

Comment: So, what is your question, is this a feature request or an article reporting your findings? Both are considered off topic here.

Comment: Have you tried Remove Doubles?

Comment: It's possible your a person who uses only Latin letters your grasp of unicode issue could be limited as it serves other langues needs, basically my question is that if unicode can produce a solid letter in blender if it can do that at all, th e joint letters currently are separate shapes only

Comment: I guess the answer is no, since Blender treats any character as a separate one. You can convert text objects to shapes and then be free to join/merge them as you like, but this could not be easy for your workflow. I guess you could post this to blender devs as a feature request, or a bug...

Comment: yes usually what i do is that i convert the word into vector so i can weld the letters together as one shape, in this case you wont be able to edit the text later.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to convert the text to mesh <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> in object mode. After that switch to edit mode and select Remove Doubles from the Tools where you can adjust the Merge Distance.

Comment: Its the easiest solution i know, i'm dealing with meta data on the daily bases where titles need to be changed, conversion to mesh will decrease workflow productivity. it also limit the idea of fast text editing where seconds is extremely valuable in live broadcast. but thanks for your time in replying  :)

Comment: I can do the text in other software and export it as SVG but it will defeat the purpose of having an editable text in Blender